# Clarification on a map $f:X \to Y$ inducing a chain homomorphism: $f_\sharp:C_n(X)\to C_n(Y)$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Hatcher states (from *Algebraic Topology*):

> For a map $f :X\to Y$, an induced homomorphism $f_\sharp :C_n(X)\to C_n(Y)$ is defined
> by composing each singular $n$-simplex $\sigma :\Delta^n\to X$ with $f$ to get a singular $n$-simplex $f_\sharp(\sigma) = fσ :\Delta^n\to Y$.

$f$ has to be continuous, right? Otherwise what guarantees that $fσ$ is a continuous map? (which is required for it to be a singular $n$-simplex). Or, at least, we require the composition to be continuous.

Comment: Yes, $f$ has to be continuous. If Hatcher does not specify, then a map always means a continuous one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hatcher p. 1 :

> *To avoid overusing the word ‘continuous’ we adopt the convention that maps between spaces are always assumed to be continuous unless otherwise stated.*